# Tweepy max tweets

Tags: python, tweepy

I'm looking to set the max amount of tweets recieved fromt Twitter.

I have tried `count=100`but that does not seem to be working for me

```
import tweepy

api_key = ''
api_secret = ''

access_token = ''
access_token_secret = ''

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(api_key, api_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

public_tweets = api.home_timeline()

for tweet in public_tweets:
    print tweet.text

for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q="google", rpp=100, count=20, result_type="recent", include_entities=True, lang="en").items():
    print tweet.created_at, tweet.text
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `items` to set the limit you want to impose.

```
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q="google", rpp=100, count=20, result_type="recent", include_entities=True, lang="en").items(200)
```

will limit the number of tweets to 200.